# How to make link colour the same as parent div?

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover

Is there a simple rule that can be written in CSS to make all links take the standard font colour selected in the `div` they are in, but when they are hovered to go blue and when they are clicked to not permanently change colour.

I only want them to light up when they are hovered on, otherwise remain the same, the only `div` this problem is occuring in is the one below.

```css
.textundergrey {
    height: 140px;
    width: 950px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-family: "OpenSans Light", Arial, serif;
    font-size: 20px
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want the link to have the same color as the div you should use `color:inherit;` and to turn to blue when hover you should use :

```
a:hover{
    color:blue;
}
```

Also with this code links dont change color when clicked.

Try:

HTML:

```
<div id="yellow"><a href="#">Yellow</a></div>
<div id="red"><a href="#">Red</a></div>
```

CSS:

```
a{
    color:inherit;
}
a:hover{
    color:blue;
}
#yellow{
    color:yellow;
}

#red{
    color:red
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u6jBn/)

**EDIT** (from comments)

To remove underline just use `text-decoration:none;`

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/u6jBn/1/)

Comment: PERFECT! how do i stop the underline?

Comment: 10/10 thanks! if i knew how to make this the correct answer i would add it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `inherit` property :

```
a {
    color: inherit !important ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent them from changing color when they are hovered

```
a:hover{

}
```

To prevent them from changing color when clicked

```
a:active{

}
```

You can apply it globally with the code above or to that specific class:

```
.textundergrey a:active{

}
```

To color links in that specific class use:

```
.textundergrey a{
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to make links have the same colour as the rest of the text?

Answer (score 1):

```
.parent_div a{
    color:red;
}
.parent_div a:hover{
    color:blue;
}
```